# WCF inactivityTimeout

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a communicator application, which is used to communicate between users logged onto one machine. Application is based on WCF technology C#. So i have service hosted in IIS and client application (Windows Form). All functions working fine, except, after 10 min client application is disconnected from service and it is not possible to send the message again. 
I think it is about the inactivityTimeout which is set to 10 min by default. 
How to change this timeout to maximum value? 
Should it be done on the Client side or the Service side?

Service application settings:

```html
</system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="netTcpBinding"
                   openTimeout="00:05:30"
                   closeTimeout="00:05:30"
                   sendTimeout="00:05:00"
                   receiveTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000">
        <reliableSession acknowledgementInterval="00:00:1"
                         inactivityTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000"/>
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="CommunicatorService.CommunicatorService" >
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" contract="CommunicatorService.ICommunicatorService" >
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client settings:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ICommunicatorService" receiveTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000">
                    <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" />
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://win10/CommunicatorService/Service.svc"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ICommunicatorService"
                contract="CommunicatorService.ICommunicatorService" name="NetTcpBinding_ICommunicatorService">
                <identity>
                    <servicePrincipalName value="host/Win10" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be set on the server-side, and please note that we need to use Bindingconfiguration to apply this configuration.

```
   <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpBinding"
                     openTimeout="00:10:30"
                     closeTimeout="00:10:30"
                     sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                     receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <reliableSession acknowledgementInterval="00:00:1"
                           inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
  <services>
      <service name="CommunicatorService.CommunicatorService" >
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" contract="CommunicatorService.ICommunicatorService" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBinding" >
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
</services>
```

About the meanings of these parameters, please refer to the below document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.reliablesession.inactivitytimeout?view=netframework-4.8
Some parameters may take effect on the client. 
It is advisable that we use the same settings on both the client side and the server side.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.